# What do double parentheses mean in a function call? e.g. func(foo)(bar)

Tags: python, function-call

I use this idiom all the time to print a bunch of content to standard out in utf-8 in Python 2:

```
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
```

But to be honest, I have no idea what the `(sys.stdout)` is doing. It sort of reminds me of a Javascript closure or something. But I don't know how to look up this idiom in the Python docs.

Can any of you fine folks explain what's going on here? Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`.getwriter` returns a <strike>function</strike> callable object; you are merely calling it in the same line.

This question is (very respectfully) like

> What does `x+y+z` mean? I've seen `x+y` used, but what's this `+z`?.

Think of "order of operations".

Example:

```
def returnFunction():
    def myFunction():
        print('hello!')
    return myFunction
```

Demo:

```
>>> returnFunction()()
hello!
```

You could have alternatively done:

```
>>> result = returnFunction()
>>> result()
hello!
```

Perhaps this makes this clearer?

```
>>> ( returnFunction() )()
hello!
```

---

Visualization:

```
evaluation step 0: returnSomeFunction()()
evaluation step 1: |<-somefunction>-->|()
evaluation step 2: |<----result-------->|
```

---

`x` '(' `y` ')' is, like most things, a non-terminal syntactical expression... as opposed to a terminal expression (i.e. an expression which cannot be embellished), or compiler directive (like #pragma or a print statement). In math-speak, it is just an expression.

So of course in say python2, `print print 5` would by a syntactical error (since a print statement is basically a terminal expression). However, the function calls are non-terminal expressions (of which there can be many kinds, but this is probably a "python expression"), just like the pure mathematical functions they are inspired by. You can combine "python expressions" with operators and syntax which gives you a "python expression", and thus build more complicated expressions out of small ones. That is one of the essences of programming. (Replace "python" above with whatever programming language. Some languages call these EXPR when they define their syntax. This is a gross but accurate generalization. I'm not sure how my explanation changes as you consider things like operator fixity, associativity, non-grammar languages or preparsing extensions, etc.)

Comment: However, in this example the second set of parantheses is a *class instantiation operator*, not a function call. (See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) Also, please do not edit the question to match your answer.

Comment: @junjanes: Thank you for pointing out that detail (though a "class instantiation operator" is in fact just class (callable object) or factory function (callable object)). You misinterpret though the rationale for editing: it is not to make my answer "match better", but rather to better summarize the question. (Incidentally, it does not in fact make my answer match better, anymore than it makes *your* answer match better.) In light of your concern though, I will re-add the original title in the question.

Answer (score 7):

`codecs.getwriter('utf-8')` returns a class with `StreamWriter` behaviour and whose objects can be initialized with a stream.

```
>>> codecs.getwriter('utf-8')
<class encodings.utf_8.StreamWriter at 0x1004b28f0>
```

Thus, you are doing something similar to:

```
sys.stdout = StreamWriter(sys.stdout)
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the wrapper function with the double parentheses of python flexibility.

Example:

1. `funcwrapper`

   ```
   def funcwrapper(y):
       def abc(x):
           return x * y + 1
       return abc

   result = funcwrapper(3)(5)
   print(result)
   ```
2. `funcWrapper`

   ```
   def xyz(z):
       return z + 1

   def funcwrapper(y):
       def abc(x):
           return x * y + 1
       return abc

   result = funcwrapper(3)(xyz(4))
   print(result)
   ```

Comment: This essentially code-only answer merely seems to reiterate the earlier answers from several years before. If you want to demonstrate something specific, please explain what that is and how this answer is contributing towards answering the actual question here.