# What is this joblib Parallel syntax doing? So many parentheses

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, joblib

Scikit-learn often uses `joblib` to parallelize with calls like `Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs)(delayed(function)(param_to_function) for param_to_function in iterable)`.

[This helpful question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476825/what-do-double-parentheses-mean-in-a-function-call-e-g-funcstuffstuff) indicate that this double-parenthesis business means the second set is passed to whatever is returned by the call involving the first set, which makes a lot of sense if the thing returned is a callable.

But here the thing returned by `Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs)` should be a `Parallel` object, right? And then we're passing it a `generator` object given by the loop in the second parenthetical. You shouldn't be able to directly pass a generator to a class after construction like that. There should be some function call between the object and the input. Or in python is there `__some_special_function__` that works with this syntax?

What is this syntax doing, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "special function" is probably just a [`__call__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__). An instance of a class with that method can be called just like a function. In this case, Parallel presumably defines `__call__` to accept a generator.

(Note, that's not to say it's a good idea to write code like your example. It's needlessly confusing.)