# Python. Another bracket next to a function

Tags: python, function, brackets

I have code as below.

```
x = inputs
if conv_first:
    x = conv(x)
    if batch_normalization:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    if activation is not None:
        x = Activation(activation)(x)
```

Here, I dont understand how x = BatchNormalization()(x) works (just like the same, x = Activation(activation)(x) too). If it was BatchNormalization(x), it would have been easy.

Anyone can explain in a concise way what it is and how it works?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The term is parentheses. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476825/what-do-double-parentheses-mean-in-a-function-call-e-g-funcstuffstuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure that is the case, but the syntax is possible if the first called object returns another function.

Consider this code:

```
def f(arg):
    print(arg)

def g():
    return f

x = "hi"

g()(x)  # equivalent to f(x), since f is what g returns
```

Notice thay `g()` returns the function `f` without actually executing it, which is why there's no parentheses on `g`'s `return` statement.

Answer (score 4):

Both seem to be classes that implement `__call__()`. Then `BatchNormalization()` creates an instance and `(x)` calls `.__call__(x)` on the instance.