# Why (lambda x: x * 99 + x)(1 ** 5 * 5) equals 500

Tags: python

Why output of this line `(lambda x: x * 99 + x) (1 ** 5 * 5)` in Python is 500 while `x` is not defined?

Comment: But `x` *is* defined within the scope of the lambda.

Comment: the lambda defines x as an input parameter then acts upon it

Comment: `(1**5*5)` is your `x`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476825/what-do-double-parentheses-mean-in-a-function-call-e-g-funcstuffstuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `(1 ** 5 * 5)` is passed as an argument to a lambda function.

```
(lambda x: x * 99 + x)(1 ** 5 * 5)
```

lambda takes input as x and acts upon it. If you have any other Lambda function it'll work in the same way.

```
(lambda x: x.upper())('test') # will print TEST
```

It's just like you're creating a function with arg x.

```
upper = (lambda x: x.upper())
upper('test') # will print TEST
```

`upper` here is a `lambda function` that takes `arg x` and acts upon it

```
<function __main__.<lambda>(x)>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your *lambda expression* `(lambda x: x * 99 + x) (1 ** 5 * 5)` is comprised of two parts:

1. Declaring the function:

   ```
   (lambda x: x * 99 + x)
   ```

   which is equivalent to declaring the custom function as:

   ```
   def func(x):
       return (x * 99 + x)
   ```
2. Calling the above function with argument as `(1 ** 5 * 5)`, which is equivalent to making the function call as:

   ```
   func(1 ** 5 * 5)
   # i.e. func(5)      ## 1**5*5 => 5
   ```

Because `5 * 99 + 5` is equivalent to `500`. That's the answer you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

let's review your code
`(lambda x: x * 99 + x) (1 ** 5 * 5)` 
that's mean `x*99+x`
you'r input is `(1**5*5)` which equals 5 that's mean `x=5`
so `5*99+5=500`

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down.

A lambda is basically a function. In your case, it has one input (`x`) and the return statement of `x * 99 + x`. It is then called with `(1 ** 5 * 5)`.

This means that `(1 ** 5 * 5)` is `x`.

You can now do the math:

```
1 ** 5 * 5
> 1 * 5
> 5

x * 99 + x
> 5 * 99 + x
> 500
```